# NestJs initialize module similar to moduleInit while being Request scoped

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, nestjs

I need to initialise a Kafka consumer at module initialisation. But the service I'm setting this up in has a dependency on a REQUEST scoped service. Because of this, moduleInit inside my kafka consumer service is not being triggered. I'm not sure how I'd settle this.

What alternatives are available to me here?

Eg

requestScoped.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestScopedService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
  ) {}
```

kafka.consumer.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class KafkaConsumer implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private requestScopedService: RequestScopedService,
  )

  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log ('I need to set up my kafka consumer here');
    const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'my-group' })
    await consumer.connect()

    await consumer.subscribe({ topics: ['topic-A'] })
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message, heartbeat, pause }) => {
            console.log (" I will listen to all incoming messages ")
        },
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to make `onModuleInit` work when `REQUEST` scoped. You could pass the request to the `KafkaConsumer` and use [`moduleRef.resolve`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#getting-current-sub-tree)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'm not sure how I'd pass the request to `KafkaConsumer`. I need the `KafkaConsumer` to run once when the application starts since it is not going to depend on a request.

Comment: How do you make use of this `KafkaConsumer`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I've updated the post with the kafka setup. It needs to run once. Afterwards any time a message is published to `topic-A`  (through a kafka producer), `eachMessage` will automatically read it.